# Copy Paste of Feature in Vector Layer Throws Error in QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis

I just upgraded to latest release of QGIS (QGIS version 2.18.10 64bit, QGIS code revision 59e0f78). When I try to copy/paste a feature in a vector layer, I get:

> Could not commit changes to layer reader
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added - geometry type is not
>   compatible with the current layer.

Copy/paste worked fine with 2.18.9 and previous versions. Anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: I get the error with polygon and Line geometries, and the error occurs when I try to copy/paste to the same layer as the source feature. Just checked the QGIS Bug list and it is a known bug (Bug report #16770) with v2.18.10. I went back to v2.18.9 and all is good again.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, it is a known bug which has, according to the [bug tracker](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16770), been taken care of. The next point release is due tomorrow (2017/07/21), so we should hopefully see that bug corrected soon!